# How do I make food?

Tags: planet-crafter

In *The Planet Crafter*, I'm building my base, and I have enough food for now. I don't have any machines to make food, but I know I'm going to eventually run out. I guess that, like with water, I'm going to be able to make food.

How do I make food?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Craft a [Food Grower](https://planet-crafter.fandom.com/wiki/Food_growers):

> Food growers are machines that provide a way for edible crops to be grown inside buildings. They are a staple for making food that can be consumed or used in crafting recipes.

A T1 food grower becomes available when oxygen levels reach 12.00 ppt and the T2 becomes available when biomass reaches 35.00t.

T1 food grower materials:

- 1x Aluminum
- 1x Water Bottle
- 1x Iron